# To grep from file to get expected result

Tags: linux, awk, sed, command-line, grep

I have file contains variable **ans** with some values defined. i am trying to get all those variables using grep command. i want to list them on basis of **"="** sign. i know using **grep "ans" Test.txt** will list out all the **ans** variable. but that is not what i am looking for. if i do **grep "ans=" Test.txt** it should list all variables present with name **ans**.

Please help me how can i make this work

```
test.txt

    ans= 10;
    ans =11;
    ans   = 5;
    ans   =    8;
```

the normal grep command o/p:-

```
grep ans test.txt

ans= 10;
ans =11;
ans   = 5;
ans   =    8;
```

Expected grep command o/p:-

```
grep "ans=" test.txt

ans= 10;
ans =11;
ans   = 5;
ans   =    8;
```

Comment: Your grep output and expected output looks same, what's the difference n it? Kindly do confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : The expected grep command  output won't give us the result as normal grep command output. what i am looking for is on basis on variable name ans and "=" sign which looks like grep "ans=" test.txt, i am expecting normal command output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v key='ans=' '
{
   s = $0
   gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", s)
}
s ~ "^" key {
   print
   exit
}' test.txt

    ans= 10;
    ans =11;
    ans   = 5;
    ans   =    8;
```

Comment: first option doesn't provide any output! can you check once command please

Comment: second one is working fine. @anubhava can you please me, if want to tweak to get only the first result element ! How can i tweak command

Comment: Do you want to get part before = only or just the first record?

Comment: i meant when i execute below command 

awk -v key='ans=' '{s = $0; gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", s)} s ~ "^" key' test.txt

it should provide output as below
    ans= 10;

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep 'ans *=' file
    ans= 10;
    ans =11;
    ans   = 5;
    ans   =    8;
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide better sample input/output that can be used to thoroughly test your requirements.